# Json event does not work, and the weekday is not right

Tags: javascript, json

On my calendar there are dates that have events. The dates with the events should be highlighted with data received from a `JSON` call. When I click on an event date the event should be shown. The problem is my `JSON` data is not being fetched and the events don't show. Also, the weekday isn't right.

My `showInfo` code that makes the `JSON` request is below. The [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Hooligancat/pen/XgWboJ/) shows the full code example.

```
 // show info
function showInfo(event) {
  // link 
  var url = 'https://codepen.io/nakome/pen/EWBMzm.css';
  // get json
  getjson(url, function(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
      // if has envent add class
      if(_('[data-id="' + key + '"]')){
        _('[data-id="' + key + '"]').classList.add('event');
      }
      if (event === key) {
        _('#calendar_data').classList.toggle('show_data');
        // template info
        var data = '<a href="#" class="hideEvent" '+
            'onclick="return hideEvent();">&times;</a>'+
            '<h3>' + obj[key].type + '</h3>' +
            '<dl>' +
            '<dt><dfn>Title:</dfn></dt><dd>' + obj[key].title + '</dd>' +
            '<dt><dfn>Hour:</dfn></dt><dd>' + obj[key].time + '</dd>' +
            '<dt><dfn>Venue:</dfn></dt><dd>' + obj[key].venue + '</dd>' +
            '<dt><dfn>Location:</dfn></dt><dd>' + obj[key].location + '</dd>' +
            '<dt><dfn>Description:</dfn></dt><dd>' + obj[key].desc + '</dd>' +
            '<dt><dfn>More Info:</dfn></dt><dd><a href="' + obj[key].more +
            '" title="More info">Here</a></dd>' +
            '</dl>';

        return _('#calendar_data').innerHTML = data;
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
}
// toggle event show or hide
function hideEvent(){
    _('#calendar_data').classList.toggle('show_data');
}
```

Comment: I tidied up your question so it was more meaningful especially considering our previously related post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44332814/calendar-start-weeks-at-monday). The updated edits need to go through peer review before they are approved.

Comment: Also - can you clarify what you mean by the weekday is not right?

Comment: Sorry, I have a new theme, but instead of making a new question in the original post, I also inadvertently rejected your changes (could restore but probably).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your showInfo() was commented out at the start of the calendar() function. Remove the comment so this:

```
// showInfo();
```

Becomes this:

```
showInfo();
```

I have updated the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Hooligancat/pen/XgWboJ) for the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44332814/calendar-start-weeks-at-monday) here so you can see that the events are showing up. I'm not sure what you meant by the 'weekday is not right'.

Comment: Day 6 (number) is highlighted in red and weekday So (word) is highlighted in blue, but it would have to be blue Tuesday.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following, it works partly, only the Sunday gets no other color, do not know why.

```
 // Days of week
 html += '<tr class="week_cal">';

 for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  if (day -1 == i) {
    html += '<th class="week_event">' + weekdays[i] + '</th>';
  } else {
    html += '<th>' + weekdays[i] + '</th>';
  }
}

html += '</tr>';
html += '</thead>';
```

Comment: Can not really help me?